# c# implement contextual help on dll to use on designtime

Tags: c#

I have develop some dll libary in c #; now I need to know if there is the possibility to insert in my projects a contextual help that will show during a designtime works when a customer will call methods and events of my library like a screenshot visible at this link
[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/ccontexthelp.jpg/]

[Click here for full image](http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/6439/ccontexthelp.jpg)

Is possible do this? Some idea? Thanks a lot to everyone

By Jumpier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is created in code using [xml comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx).

```
/// <summary>
/// This text will show up in the contextual help box.
/// </summary>
public void SomePublicMethod() {
    ...
}
```

To ship a dll with this metadata, [generate xml documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> To generate an XML documentation file for a Visual C# project
>   With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
>   Click the Build tab.
>   On the Build page, select XML documentation file. By default, the file is created under the specified output path, for example, "bin\Debug\Projectname.XML".

Answer (score 1):

It is called `XML Docs`. Here's the basic syntax.

```
/// <summary>
///  This class performs an important function.
/// </summary>
public class MyClass{ }
```

- [XML Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)
- [Recommended Tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add XML code comments to your classes, properties, and methods.
When building your app, check the Build option for Xml Documentation File.
You then distribute the xml file with your DLL.

In Visual studio, type /// on the line before any code element (class, property, enum, method) and the appropriate comment stub will be added.